# JavaScript - cannot leave while loop, why?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, imgur

I am building a small project website to learn more about WebDev.

I try to get random images from imgur.
It works good to the point where I want to "filter" the removed.png redirection if an image didnt exist or was deleted. But I keep getting stuck in an endless loop. Maybe someone can help me out here find the error!

Example snippet (It will stop your browser if you run it tho):

```js
function fetch() {
 var src = document.getElementById("imageGrid").innerHTML = "";
 var max = 50;
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < max+1; i++)
 {
  var tries = 0;
  var validPic = true;
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.id = i;
  img.height = 64;
  img.width = 64
  while(validPic)
  {
   tries ++;
   img.src = generate_string(5);
   if(testRedirect(img.src))
   {
    var validPic = false;
    var src = document.getElementById("imageGrid");
    src.appendChild(img);
   }
  }
 }
 $("img").addClass("loadedImage");
 $("img").attr("onmouseover","imageEnlarge(this)");
}

function testRedirect(url) {
 var actualUrl = "";
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
 xhr.send();
 if (url != xhr.responseURL) {
  console.log("redirected to: " + xhr.responseURL);
  return false;
 }else{
  console.log("no redirecton found");
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

function generate_string(length) { 
 var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
 var string = ""; 
    var i;
 for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  string += chars[Math.floor((Math.random() * chars.length) + 0)];
 }  
 return "http://i.imgur.com/" + string + ".jpg";
}

function imageEnlarge(x) {
 
 document.getElementById('bigImage').src = x.src;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="scripts/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<button id='fetchButton' onclick="fetch()">Imgur</button> 
<div id="imageGrid"></div>
<img id="bigImage" width="400" height="400"/>
<script>
</script>




</body>

</html>
```

I considered the [marked as duplicate] - Question link.
And tried to apply it to my case.
This is what I got now. I think I dont really grasp the asynchonous stuff just now. Can someone help me out?

New code:

```js
function fetch() {
 var src = document.getElementById("imageGrid").innerHTML = "";
 var max = 50;
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < max+1; i++)
 {
  var validPic = true;
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.id = i;
  img.height = 64;
  img.width = 64
  while(validPic)
  {
   var validImgur = false;
   img.src = generate_string(5);
   testRedirect(img.src, function(x){var validImgur = x; });
   if(validImgur)
   {
    var validPic = false;
    var src = document.getElementById("imageGrid");
    src.appendChild(img);
   }
  }
 }
 $("img").addClass("loadedImage");
 $("img").attr("onmouseover","imageEnlarge(this)");
}

function testRedirect(url, fn) {
 
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', url, true);

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   if(url != xhr.responseURL) {
    console.log("redirection to: " + xhr.responseURL);
    fn(false);
   }else {
    console.log("no redirection found");
    fn(true);
   }
  }
 };
 
 xhr.send();
 
}


function generate_string(length) { 
 var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
 var string = ""; 
    var i;
 for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  string += chars[Math.floor((Math.random() * chars.length) + 0)];
 }  
 return "http://i.imgur.com/" + string + ".jpg";
}

function imageEnlarge(x) {
 
 document.getElementById('bigImage').src = x.src;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="scripts/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<button id='fetchButton' onclick="fetch()">Imgur</button> 
<div id="imageGrid"></div>
<img id="bigImage" width="400" height="400"/>
<script>
</script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `testRedirect` is asynchronous

Comment: I am voting to leave this question closed. Try asking a new question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.